# Drawer doesn't open after fast double click. Primarily because the drawer and its state are out of sync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

#### Project to replicate the issue

https://github.com/jainniket/drawer-issue

#### Code

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
         <Button
           title="Open Drawer"
           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
         />
        <Text>Notifications</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

#### Github issue

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1960

#### Current Behavior

There is a Hamburger Menu on whose click `DrawerOpen` action is triggered.
But when, that menu is tapped twice very fast, the drawer opens and closes back, but the state is still set as Open.

So the error is, once the menu is clicked, it opens the drawer, but in the transition phase, when the drawer is opening, another tap happens which eventually happens to be on the View being presented by Drawer. This tap forces the menu to close back but the action `DrawerClose` doesn't get registered.

Whereas the redux state says the current route as `DrawerOpen` even though the drawer is closed. So any further taps on the menu icon becomes un-responsive.

Reason - The drawer presented and drawer state are out of sync.

#### Expected Behavior

The double tap should be disabled.
The presenting view of drawer shouldn't take any touch event.

#### Environment

- react-navigation -> ^1.0.0-beta.11
- react-native -> 0.45.1
- node -> v7.6.0
- npm or yarn -> v4.1.2

Comment: github issue https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1960

Comment: Could you please incorporate the relevant portion of code into your question itself? First of, because SO questions should be readable standalone and also because it drastically improves chances of someone helping you, because not many people are willing to search through your whole repository.

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/175

Comment: @dirkk thank you for the suggestion. I've incorporated the code snippet.